# set php session on success of ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have problem .i am making ajax call to a php file that will check credentials, if true i want to redirect to page , but if false i want to show error. I have little bit problem . Here is my code ajax Code.

```
  function Login(val1, val2) {
                alert(val1 + "\n" + val2);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "login.php",
                    data: 'username='+val1+'&password='+val2,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        if(data=="true"){

                            window.location.replace('./admin/index.php');
                        }else
                        $("#Area").html(data);
                    }
                });
```

and this is my php code.

```
<?php

  require_once '/admin/DbHelper.php';
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $name = $_POST['username'];

    $query = "select * from user_login where userName='$name' and userPass='$pass'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    $row=  mysqli_fetch_array($result);


    if ($row > 0) {
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $name;
        echo "true";    } else {
        echo '<label style="color:red"> Invalid User Name or Passowrd !</label>';
    }
}
```

i can't understand where i should set session. please help me.

Comment: which page you have put the ajax call?

Comment: i have  home.php , from where i called above ajax function by passing two arguments

Comment: add session_start at the top of the home.php page and login page

Comment: yeah i have added , but where to set session variable . Actually i am passing my variables to ajax function , and php checks true or false , if true than i want to set session and redirect to page , but if not than show error message to model. problem is that , redirected page is shown on modal .

Comment: A session can set only by adding session_start at the top of any page. so you have to add session_start at the top of every page where you want to use  $_SESSION['userName']. You have placed $_SESSION['userName'] in the right place

Comment: but it redirects to login page.

Comment: put header("Location:home.php") in if($row>0)

Comment: than it will sow all home.php in modal dialog . :-(